# Apache rewrite rule for replace part of the URL

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I have troubles with rewrite the **last trailing slash** to **.html**

Example:

/something/something2/ to /something/something2.html

/something/ to /something.html

I tried with, but without success for the moment:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*+)/$ /$1.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to ask to find an answer...

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/$ /$1.html [R=301,NC,L]
```